# Deriving equations for memristor

Tags: memristor

I'm going through Chua's 1971 memristor paper. I am stuck on a part that I believe in pretty crucial. It is

> Observe that the, value of the incremental memristance
>   (memductance) at any time to depends upon the time
>   integral of the memristor current (voltage) from t = - co
>   to t= to. Hence, while the memristor behaves like an ordinary
>   resistor at a given instant of time to, its resistance
>   (conductance) depends on the complete past history of the
>   memristor current (voltage). - Page 511(page 5 of the pdf) top of the right column

http://www.cpmt.org/scv/meetings/chua.pdf

I'm not seeing the integral from any of the equations 1 through 4 that are presented in the paper.

When I read the section in question, this is what comes to mind, but I cannot see the derivation. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

[image]

To expand further on what I have tried

[image]

Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong with my math? Is it a physics thing possibly? I'm not seeing how current gets into this at all. I realize memristors is a rather newish topic that not many people are aware of or even care about.

Comment: You know, maybe the equation is supposed to be as I think. I cant find it anywhere on the net.

Comment: Your question is not clear and has some flaws: (1) Where does the formula after "It can be shown that M(q(t))=..." come from? (2) That formula is obviously wrong: unit of M is resistance; but the unit of the integral is charge (current times time). (3) Also: please use integrated math folmula edititing (backslash dollar) instead if images of formulas if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have misunderstood the proposition of Chua: *"Observe that the value of the incremental memristance (memductance) at any time \$t_0\$ depends upon the time integral of the memristor current (voltage) from \$t = - \infty \$ to \$t= t_0\$."*

In fact the observation just says that \$M \$ is function of the integral of the current 
$$
M=M (q(t_0))=M\left ( \int_{-\infty}^{t_0}i (\tau)\mathrm d \tau\right)
$$
and that $W $ is function of the integral of the voltage 
$$
W=W (\varphi(t_0))=W\left ( \int_{-\infty}^{t_0} v(\tau)\mathrm d \tau\right)
$$

You have nothing to calculate.